# Get SQL Cursor Fetched Data in list of Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, sql, database-performance

I have multiple queries in nested for each loop with millions of records its tack long to process queries with each iteration of loop from asp.net MVC then I have create a cursor instead of executing multiple queries from the action but can't retrieve fetched rows in list/variable.

SQL:

```sql
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_get_AllofPostings]
    @comp nvarchar(max),
    @TNumber int
    as
    begin
    
    DECLARE @Id NVARCHAR(128), @AccountCode varchar(max), @TrasactionNumber int, @LedgerNumber int, @RefCode varchar(50), @IsDebit bit, @Amount float, @pcomp nvarchar(max), @CreateDate datetime, @status bit
    -- declare cursor
    DECLARE postings_cursor CURSOR FOR
      SELECT *  FROM Postings where TrasactionNumber = @TNumber and CoId=@comp and Amount IS NOT NULL 
    OPEN postings_cursor;
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM postings_cursor INTO @Id, @AccountCode, @TrasactionNumber, @LedgerNumber, @RefCode, @IsDebit, @Amount, @pcomp, @CreateDate, @status
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
        --do somthing here
        Declare @LAccountName nvarchar(max), @LGLAccount int, @GLName nvarchar(max), @Gaccountcode varchar(50)
            SET @LAccountName = (select AccountName from Ledgers where CoId=@comp and AccountCode=@AccountCode)
            SET @LGLAccount =   (select GLAccount from Ledgers where CoId=@comp and AccountCode=@AccountCode)
            SET @GLName =       (select GLName from GLAccounts where CoId=@comp and Keyid = @LGLAccount)
            SET @Gaccountcode = (select Name from Groups where CoId=@comp and Code = @AccountCode)
        FETCH NEXT FROM postings_cursor INTO @Id, @AccountCode, @TrasactionNumber, @LedgerNumber, @RefCode, @IsDebit, @Amount, @pcomp, @CreateDate, @status
        END;
    CLOSE postings_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE postings_cursor;
END
```

C#:

```
var posting = db.sp_get_AllofPostings(comp, item.Number);
```

Comment: The wise SQL Server gurus in every place I've worked have consistently told me to avoid using cursors. I've *never* seen one hooked up to C#.  Is your C# code simple trying to call the stored procedure?  What is the type of `db`. What is `db.sp_get_AllofPostings`?

Comment: Not seeing why a cursor is needed here. Why not just use joins?